# Android "()" not treated as string

Tags: android

I have a problem with one line of code, which goes like this:

```
string = string.replaceAll("sin()", "");
```

As you can see, in a string, all "sin()" need to be replaced with "". But the problem is that () is not treated as string and so this line of code replaces "sin()" with "()". Moreover, Android studio reports warning on the () saying empty group. I tried solving this with escape character, but that doesn't work. Would following code work by any chance?

```
String compare = "sin()";
string = string.replaceAll(compare, "");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replaceAll`'s first parameter is a regular expression, of which `(` and `)` are special characters. You would instead need to use

```
string = string.replaceAll("sin\\(\\)", "");
```

Note the use of `\\` - `\` is actually a special character in Java strings, so you must first escape the `\` by using `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String z = "sin() is equal sin()";
    Log.d("TEST",z);
    z = z.replaceAll("sin\\(\\)", "");
    Log.d("TEST",z);
```

Gives following output:

```
sin() is equal sin()
 is equal
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your `(` and `)` because its a special charaters
So you need to use "`\\`"
example:

```
string = string.replaceAll("sin\\(\\)", "");
```